# JButton and its Location methods acting very weird

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, grid-layout

my problem is, that when I create a JButton, whithin its constructor, I set its location to some relative coordinates, say x = 5, and y = 6, using the following code:

```
this.setLocation(new Point(x, y));
```

but after I am trying to get its location using the getLocation() method, it always returns 0,0. Please note that this happens for every JButton I am trying to place on a grid layout powered JFrame, and during the debugging process, I have also noted that their location is being properly instantiated.

Can someone explain to me why this happens, and if I can fix it somehow?

EDIT:

The constructor (The brick class that I made, extends JButton):

```
public Brick(int posx, int posy) {
        this.setLocation(new Point(posx, posy));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I make about 100+ of them in 2 for loops:

```
   for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 15; column++) {
    Brick brickie = new Brick(row, column);
    }
   }
```

But afterwards, if I wanna pick a brick and check its location like this:

```
Point brickLocation = brickie.getLocation();
```

both `brickLocation.x == 0` and `brickLocation.y == 0`

Comment: Could you post some more code? Like the constructor you are talking about and how you are getting the location back?

Comment: 1) Don't set the location of buttons. 2) Don't call for the location of buttons before the GUI is packed and made visible. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change button location when it is automatically assigned by layout manager (your GridLayout). That is why you are always getting the same value back - layout just overwrites it.

To be able to change any component bounds/location (including buttons) manually - you have to set "null" as the container's layout. After that just change the location/size/bounds as you like and it will affect the components positions.

Also you don't need to use "setVisible(true)" - by default that flag is true for all components (even those that aren't displayed yet).

Comment: *"you have to set "null" as the container's layout"*  Or you might take a different and entirely better approach (and use layouts properly, as detailed by @mKorbel).

Comment: @AndrewThompson there are cases when null layout might be more useful than other approaches, but i bet this is not that kind of case. Yes, usually its better to use existing layouts (or create your own layout for some specific case).

Answer (score 2):

`JComponent(s)` can returns its coordinates, getBounds or `getLocation` only

- if container is already visible on the screen
- after `pack()`

Comment: It is a pity the OP chose the answer that will lead to more problems.  :(  +1 for providing the correct answer. :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks, its possible by override Insets(bunch of code), by why bothering with implemented and known methods